# Disable myisam engine in mysql?

Tags: mysql, myisam, percona

I want to prevent others to create `MyISAM` tables, is it possible?

I am trying install `Percona5.5` from source, compile with cmake use:

```
-DWITHOUT_MYISAM_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
```

but this cannot disable myisam engine.

Did I miss something? 
Could anyone please tell me how to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your MySQL config file:

```
disabled_storage_engines="MyISAM,BLACKHOLE,FEDERATED,ARCHIVE"
```

It will be useful for MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Note that this is only available in mysql v5.7.8 and higher. [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_disabled_storage_engines)

Answer (score 0):

Seems MyISAM is mandatory, and the parameter you mentioned can be used for controlling the other *optional* storage engines. I'm basing this on what I read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-sourcebuild-excerpt/5.5/en/source-configuration-options.html). What you can control is [setting the default storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engine-setting.html) during start-up, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> To exclude a storage engine from the build, use - DWITHOUT_engine_STORAGE_ENGINE=1. 
>   Examples:
>   -DWITHOUT_EXAMPLE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
>   -DWITHOUT_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
>   -DWITHOUT_PARTITION_STORAGE_ENGINE=1
>   If neither -DWITH_engine_STORAGE_ENGINE nor -DWITHOUT_engine_STORAGE_ENGINE are specified for a given storage engine, the engine is built as a shared module, or excluded if it cannot be built as a shared module.

However, I believe that those are just for the optional database engines.  Remember, MyISAM used to be the primary storage engine for Mysql and other storage engines such as Innodb were originally plugins that were integrated later. Therefore, Myisam is still used for the information and perforamnce schema databases.  I do not believe you can install Mysql/Percona server without having MyISAM enabled.

You could do a regular install and then as fiftystars suggested use the plugin he suggested. You can definitely control what is the default engine that database/tables are created as in Mysql as noted by pugmax.

Although, although I heard (Don't quote me on this) that they might change the performance and informations schemas to use Innodb storage engine by default in version 5.7.